# Count matching cells after each input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a formula which will count matching cells after is input is triggered.

I'm using Office Forms / Flow to get the input data.

```
+----------+---------+---------+
| id       |  name   | count   |
+----------+---------+---------+
| 1        | Mike    | 1       |
| 2        | Mike    | 2       |
| 3        | steve   | 1       |
| 4        | Mike    | 3       |
| 5        | Steve   | 2       |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

For the example above, each time 'Mike' comes into the chart, I want the count to increase by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2)
```

Comment: @M.Douda I think that tag says `excel` and `excel-formula` and this is exactly the formula you'd use to get count, should the data be in column `B`.